# Array compare with memcmp vs element by element comparsion

Tags: c, performance, loops, memcmp

Which implementation is better and why?

Element by Element comparison using a for loop or memcmp() implementation

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int b[] = {1,3,5};

memcmp(a, b, sizeof(int)*n)
```

OR

```
 for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
       if (a[i] == b[i])
        {
            /* some Code */
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memcmp` is faster: it is generally heavily optimized by the compiler to use special instructions on the cpu, loop unrolling, and other "advanced" techniques that the generated code for the simple loop (generally) won't use. However, `memcmp` can only compare byte values; it is fine in case of an array of integers, but it (probably) wouldn't work for an array of objects.